# Unity: Difference between Audio Source, Audio Listener and Audio Clip

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I would like to play some sound effects in my Unity project. 
I looked for a solution on the official website but I could not get the difference between an Audio Source, an Audio Listener and an Audio Clip. 
Is it better to add them programmatically or to use an appropriate component? 
Thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener.html => AudioSource plays AudioClip; AudioListener can record AudioClips. AudioSource and AudioListeners **are** components, AudioClip is an Asset type

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An `AudioSource` is a *component* that allows for sound to be played in your scene. It also holds the control options for the audio like `Play` `Pause` `volume` `loop` and all other properties and methods you need to control how the playback of your sounds work. This component also supports 3D audio, meaning the sound will come form the location of the `GameObject` it is on, like a persons mouth for example.
Code examples and other properties/methods for `AudioSource` can be found in the documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html)

the asset *type* `AudioClip` is used by the `AudioSource` for playback. `AudioClip` contains the file you want to play back as either compressed ogg vorbis, or uncompressed. `AudioClip` also holds all information about that clip like the `length` and `frequency`.
Full documentation on all methods and properties found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html)

You select what `AudioClip` the `AudioSource` plays by setting the `AudioSource.clip` property.

Finally you have the *component* `AudioListener`, that as the name suggest is what *listens* for the audio in your scene (that is played from an `AudioSource`). To be able to hear sounds in your scene you need an `AudioListener` (There is one by default on the main camera, and is limited to *one* per scene) and be in the range of your `AudioSource`. Just like `AudioSource` the `AudioListener` also has a `volume` property, but they are **not** the same. The `volume` property of the `AudioListener` dictates the volume for the entire game, where on an `AudioSource` it only dictates the volume for that specific instance.
the full documentation expliaining all properties and methods can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioListener.html)