# Unity c# How can i make countdown tick-tock sound?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, countdowntimer

I am making a tower defense game. And i want to make tick-tock countdown sound but when i call "play sound" function in the code, it just keeps infinitely looping. i also used coroutine yet it didn't work. Please Help me.

==================================================================

Wave Spawner

```
public float timeBetweenWaves = 34f;
 private float countdown = 34f;
   
 void Update()
 {
     if (waveNumber <= 40)
     {
         SpawnCount();
     }
 }
 void SpawnCount()
 {
     GameObject[] enemyFind = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
     int enemyCount = enemyFind.Length;
     if (enemyCount == 0) // if enemy is 0, countdown goes 34 to 0
     {
         if (countdown <= 0f) // if countdown becomes 0, wave starts and countdown stops at 34
         {
             StartCoroutine(SpawnWave()); // wave starts here
             countdown = timeBetweenWaves; // countdown initializes
         }
         
         countdown -= Time.deltaTime; // countdown goes 34 to 0
         waveCountDownText.text = Mathf.Round(countdown).ToString();
         // I want to play countdown tick-tock sound here until countdown becomes 0
         //FindObjectOfType<SoundManager>().Play("Timer"); // this didn't work
     }
 }
```

Sound Manager

```
public Sound[] sounds;
 public static SoundManager instance;
 void Awake()
 {
     if (instance == null)
     {
         instance = this;
     }
     else
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
         return;
     }
     DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
     foreach (Sound s in sounds)
     {
         s.source = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
         s.source.clip = s.clip;
         s.source.volume = s.volume;
         s.source.pitch = s.pitch;
         s.source.loop = s.loop;
     }
 }
 void Start()
 {
     Play("Theme");
 }
 public void Play (string name) // i used this function and sound name is "Timer"
 {
     Sound s = Array.Find(sounds, sound => sound.name == name);
     if (s == null)
     {
         Debug.LogWarning("Sound: " + name + "Not Found!");
         return;
     }
     s.source.Play();
 }
```

Comment: Please make sure to use the correct tags. Your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now

Answer (score 0):

Try using AudioSource

```
public AudioSource[] audioSource;
public AudioClip[] clips;

audioSource [source].clip = clips [0];
audioSource[source].Play ();
```

Please read this as well, it might help [Unity: Difference between Audio Source, Audio Listener and Audio Clip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197379/unity-difference-between-audio-source-audio-listener-and-audio-clip)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Might be easier this if you add this code all you need to do is change the tick and tock sounds in the ticking array to whatever you want.

```
public class Clock : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioS;
    public AudioClip[] ticking; 
    void Start()
    {
        audioS = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        StartCoroutine(TickingClock());
    }

    public bool tick = true; 
    IEnumerator TickingClock()
    {
        int x= 0; 
        while(tick)
        {
            x++;
            if(x % 2 == 0)
            {
                audioS.PlayOneShot(ticking[0], 1f);
            }
            else
            {
                audioS.PlayOneShot(ticking[1], 1f);
            }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

        }
    }
}
```

To turn off the ticking you just need to make the bool false :).
If you want to call is whenever you may need to make a new method that triggers is when called.

Something like.

```
// call this from a game Controler script :) 
public void CallClock(){
    StartCoroutine(TickingClock());
}
```